# Koin NullPointerException when trying to test ViewModel injection in a Kotlin Android App

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, kotlin, koin

I'm trying to test that a ViewModel has successfully had a repository injected into it, in a test. However, I get a NPE. The code works fine for the actual app, just not the test. I think it's not correctly finding my ViewModel.

This is the code:

```
    package com.waynecovell.kotlinbasics

import android.arch.lifecycle.Observer
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.waynecovell.kotlinbasics.data.Workout
import com.waynecovell.kotlinbasics.data.WorkoutRepository
import com.waynecovell.kotlinbasics.data.WorkoutRepositoryTestImpl
import com.waynecovell.kotlinbasics.ui.WorkoutViewModel
import org.junit.After
import org.junit.Assert
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.koin.android.viewmodel.ext.koin.viewModel
import org.koin.dsl.module.Module
import org.koin.dsl.module.module
import org.koin.standalone.StandAloneContext.startKoin
import org.koin.standalone.StandAloneContext.stopKoin
import org.koin.standalone.inject
import org.koin.test.KoinTest
import org.koin.test.declareMock
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations

class WorkoutKoinTest : KoinTest {

    val viewModel: WorkoutViewModel by inject<WorkoutViewModel>()
    val repository by inject<WorkoutRepository>()

    @Mock
    lateinit var uiData: Observer<List<Workout>>

    val workoutModule : Module = module {
        viewModel { WorkoutViewModel(get()) }
        single<WorkoutRepository> { WorkoutRepositoryTestImpl() }
    }

    @Before
    fun before() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        startKoin(
            listOf(workoutModule)
        )
        declareMock<WorkoutViewModel>()
        //declareMock<WorkoutRepository>()
    }

    @After
    fun after() {
        stopKoin()
    }


    @Test
    fun testKoinRepo() {
        //data
        val workouts = repository.getWorkouts()

        //observe
        viewModel.getWorkouts().observeForever(uiData)

        //has data
        Assert.assertNotNull(viewModel.workoutData.value)

    }
}
```

Koin Log:

```
2019-03-06 17:33:21:771 (KOIN)::[i] [PrintLogger] display debug = false
2019-03-06 17:33:21:803 (KOIN)::[i] [definition] declare Factory [name='WorkoutViewModel',class='com.waynecovell.kotlinbasics.ui.WorkoutViewModel']
2019-03-06 17:33:21:803 (KOIN)::[i] [definition] declare Single [name='WorkoutRepository',class='com.waynecovell.kotlinbasics.data.WorkoutRepository']
2019-03-06 17:33:21:803 (KOIN)::[i] [modules] loaded 2 definitions
2019-03-06 17:33:21:803 (KOIN)::[i] [modules] loaded in 5.670703 ms
2019-03-06 17:33:21:803 (KOIN)::[i] [Koin] started in 28.810215 ms
2019-03-06 17:33:21:804 (KOIN)::[i] [mock] declare mock for class com.waynecovell.kotlinbasics.ui.WorkoutViewModel (Kotlin reflection is not available)
2019-03-06 17:33:21:804 (KOIN)::[i] [definition] override Factory [name='WorkoutViewModel',class='com.waynecovell.kotlinbasics.ui.WorkoutViewModel']
2019-03-06 17:33:21:809 (KOIN)::[i] +-- 'com.waynecovell.kotlinbasics.ui.WorkoutViewModel'
2019-03-06 17:33:21:870 (KOIN)::[i] \-- (*) Created
2019-03-06 17:33:21:873 (KOIN)::[i] +-- 'com.waynecovell.kotlinbasics.data.WorkoutRepository'
2019-03-06 17:33:21:876 (KOIN)::[i] \-- (*) Created
2019-03-06 17:33:21:876 (KOIN)::[i] +-- 'com.waynecovell.kotlinbasics.ui.WorkoutViewModel'
2019-03-06 17:33:21:877 (KOIN)::[i] \-- (*) Created
2019-03-06 17:33:21:898 (KOIN)::[i] [Koin] close context
```

NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.waynecovell.kotlinbasics.WorkoutKoinTest.testKoinRepo(WorkoutKoinTest.kt:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: did you find a solution? could you post it?

Comment: @LunaVulpo my solution was to stop using Kotlin and I haven't touched it to this day